# DAX average not in date period

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, dax

What would the equivalent DAX be for this SQL?

`SELECT AVG(CountRows) FROM pbi.FactVend AS FV JOIN pbi.DimAsset AS DA ON DA.KEY_Asset = FV.KEY_Asset WHERE CAST(FV.KEY_VendDate AS Date) NOT BETWEEN DA.ExcludedFromDate AND DA.ExcludedToDate`

I have two tables, Vend and Asset. I want to exclude the rows from Vend where the VendDate is in an excluded period. Something like below however I can't get the DAX right. If i filter Vend it cannot see the Asset columns also doesn't seem to like being supplied convert date, KEY_VendDate is Int YYYYMMDD...

```
Average Cup Vends = 
CALCULATE(AVERAGE(Vend[CountRows]), 
FILTER(Vend, NOT(DATESBETWEEN(CONVERT(Vend[KEY_VendDate], DATETIME), Asset[Excluded From Date], Asset[Excluded To Date])))
```

[image]

Comment: Can someone help me with this please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things I don't understand but I assume:

1. Assets[ProductKey] has unique values.

[image]

2. Vends (which from now on I'll call Transactions) contains one column
   related to Assets[ProductKey]
3. Transactions[Date] is a Date/Time column

[image]

4. Transactions is related to a Dates Table, which is not related to
   Assets.

I don't know how you're trying to use the measurement, but I hope the following example can help you find the right path.

I excluded Assets[ProductKey] only on January, as you can see in the assets table image, ie:

- Assets[ProductKey]=21 was excluded from 1/21/2021 00:00 to 1/22/2021
  00:00,
- Assets[ProductKey]=22 was excluded from 1/22/2021 00:00 to
  1/23/2021 00:00 and so on

You can access the columns in the expanded Transactions table through RELATED.

```
FILTER(Transactions,
NOT(AND(
    Transactions[TransactionDate]>=RELATED(Assets[ExcludedFromDate]),
    Transactions[TransactionDate]<RELATED(Assets[ExcludedToDate]))))
```

In my example. I used this:

```
AVGNonExcludedTransactions := 
VAR SMZDateContext=SUMMARIZE(CalendarDateTime,CalendarDateTime[Year],CalendarDateTime[MonthName])
VAR NonExcludedTransactions= 
FILTER(Transactions,
NOT(AND(
    Transactions[TransactionDate]>=RELATED(Assets[ExcludedFromDate]),
    Transactions[TransactionDate]<RELATED(Assets[ExcludedToDate]))))
VAR Result=
ADDCOLUMNS(SMZDateContext, "Count", CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(INTERSECT(
Transactions, NonExcludedTransactions))))
RETURN
AVERAGEX(Result,[Count])
```

[image]

... removing the highlighted rows. One day of exclusion for each [ProductKey] in the Assets table and more than one day of exclusion for each product in the Transactions table.

[image]

which can be analyzed by changing INTERSECT() to EXCEPT() and increasing granularity at the day level.

[image]

EDIT:

In this second part the objective is not to use FILTER on the Transactions table. However, I think the following approach can be improved by changing dates to numbers. And I still don't know if it's more efficient than using FILTER on a 10M row table. Probably not, because it would be necessary to have less than 100 products and more than 2M transactions

This is what the model looks like:

[image]

This time TCountR is a simpler measure:

```
TCountR = COUNTROWS(Transactions)
```

And the filter is calculated in another way. With a single DateTime column containing the exclusion period for each product within the granularity of CalendarDateTime:

```
AVGTCountRNonExcluded := 
VAR TotalRow = 
SUMMARIZE(CalendarDateTime,CalendarDateTime[Year],CalendarDateTime[MonthName])
VAR AllCJ =
CROSSJOIN(SUMMARIZE(Products,Products[ProductKey]),SUMMARIZE(CalendarDateTime,CalendarDateTime[DateTime]))
VAR Excluded=
SELECTCOLUMNS(
    GENERATE(Assets,
                    ADDCOLUMNS(
                                CROSSJOIN (
                        //Dates in Transactions should be rounded down at the hour level.
                        // -1 means that the day 1/2/2021 is not included
                        //From 1/1/2021 00:00 to 1/1/2021 23:00
                        ////
                        //Without adding or subtracting a value:
                        //From 1/1/2021 00:00 to 1/2/2021 23:00
                                            CALENDAR(Assets[ExcludedFromDate],Assets[ExcludedToDate]-1),
                                            SELECTCOLUMNS(GENERATESERIES(0,23,1),"Time",TIME([Value],0,0))),
                                "DateTime", [Date] + [Time])),
"ProductKey", Assets[ProductKey], "DateTime", [DateTime])
VAR FilteredOut=EXCEPT(AllCJ,Excluded)
VAR Result = ADDCOLUMNS(TotalRow,"Count", CALCULATE([TCountR],KEEPFILTERS(FilteredOut)))
RETURN
AVERAGEX(Result,[Count])
```

The result is the same.

[image]

EDIT 2

Why not?

If you already understood the 2nd approach, you may wonder, what if I can add a column to my Transactions table and change the [TransactionDate] format from DateTime to Date, and use a Dates Table only at the Date level.
Example:

```
1/1/2021 23:00 To 1/1/2021 00:00
1/2/2021 00:00 To 1/2/2021 00:00
```

The code gets simpler:

```
AVGCountRowsDateLevel := 
VAR TotalRow= SUMMARIZE(Dates,Dates[Year],Dates[MonthName])
VAR AllCJ=CROSSJOIN(SUMMARIZE(Products,Products[ProductKey]),SUMMARIZE(Dates,Dates[Date]))
VAR Excluded=
SELECTCOLUMNS(
    GENERATE(Assets,
    DATESBETWEEN(Dates[Date],Assets[ExcludedFromDate],Assets[ExcludedToDate]-1)),
"ProductKey", Assets[ProductKey], "Date", [Date])
VAR FilteredOut=EXCEPT(AllCJ,Excluded)
VAR Result = ADDCOLUMNS(TotalRow,"Count", CALCULATE([TCountR],KEEPFILTERS(FilteredOut)))
RETURN
AVERAGEX(Result,[Count])
```

And the result is the same

As I said at the beginning, this is an example, which I hope can help you find the solution.

Comment: Excellent what I was missing was the related key word for the asset fields, I didn't realise I had to use this to add every column for a related table, thought DAX would have a more clever way of doing this...

Comment: What DAX does not allow you is the direct relationship between tables through multiple columns (BETWEEN Date1 TO Date2 for each product) because a single product can have multiple exclusion dates and a single exclusion date can have multiple products on the same date.

Comment: Using FILTER+RELATED you are accessing the expanded Transactions table that includes the tables on the one-side of the relationship and returning the entire result table as a table filter. Using the third approach you create a table combining the exclusion conditions for both products and dates while making use of the data lineage of the tables that have a physical relationship with Transactions.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a relationship from `Assets[KEY_Asset]` to `Vend[KEY_Asset]` and `Vend[VendDate]` is formatted as a date, then you can write

```
Average Cup Vends =
CALCULATE (
    AVERAGE ( Vend[CountRows] ),
    FILTER (
        Vend,
        NOT AND (
            Vend[VendDate] > RELATED ( Asset[Excluded From Date] ),
            Vend[VendDate] < RELATED ( Asset[Excluded To Date] )
        )
    )
)
```

This requires first defining a calculated column `Vend[VendDate]` to convert `Vend[KEY_VendDate]` from YYYYMMDD to a date format. You can define such a column as follows:

```
VendDate =
DATE (
    LEFT  ( Vend[KEY_VendDate], 4 ),
    MID   ( Vend[KEY_VendDate], 5, 2 ),
    RIGHT ( Vend[KEY_VendDate], 2 )
)
```

---

Another option is to convert the `Asset` date columns into integer format instead.

```
Average Cup Vends =
CALCULATE (
    AVERAGE ( Vend[Countrows] ),
    FILTER (
        Vend,
        NOT AND (
            Vend[KEY_VendDate]
              > VALUE ( FORMAT ( RELATED ( Asset[Excluded From Date] ), "yyyymmdd" ) ),
            Vend[KEY_VendDate]
              < VALUE ( FORMAT ( RELATED ( Asset[Excluded To Date] ), "yyyymmdd" ) )
        )
    )
)
```